# Getting IBM Host on Demand to work with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, websphere

How do I get the IBM Host on Demand client to work with Internet Explorer 8?

Or do I have to get a newer version (and where) which is compatible with IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2009, IBM said that it's not compatible with IE8. I'm not sure if this has been fixed but this is what I found on their website:

> ***Support for Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 in WebSphere Host On-Demand Version 10***
>
> *Technote (FAQ)*
>
> **Question**
>
> - Does IBM WebSphere Host On-Demand Version 10 support using Microsoft Internet Explorer 8?
>
> **Answer**
>
> - Currently Host On-Demand Version 10 does not support Microsoft Internet Explorer 8. The development team is investigating the support for Internet Explorer 8 with Host On-Demand. During the download, the progress bar does not display and no download takes place. This has been tested with different levels of Java and the cached client will not install. 
>     The Download clients and Webstart clients are not affected and will load. Development is targeting fourth quarter of 2009 to have a resolution to this problem.

The [WebSphere Host on Demand page from IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/hostondemand/sysreqsdetails.html) website details more about the requirements.